Is there a way to merge the sound level sliders?
In my Windows 11 I now have a growing set of sound loudness sliders which regulate in detail how loud the sounds of given applications are.

The problem is that usually/often, when I have a headset the sound in my ears cannot be directly managed by either the headset buttons, or the keyboard ones. Whether it works depends on many parameters, including planets alignment.
I would like to get back a single loudness slider -- is this possible? (or in other words - disable the per-application loudness settings)

The top slider is the overall volume, that should be enough to just manage that one. Just don't push it too high.

@LPChip it should but it does not always. I am just off a call where I could slide it up and down and the volume was not changed. I had to explicitly slide the Zoom one for the sound to change

Then the audio source is not your windows, so you need to set the default audio device to that device, and then it will work. I bet the cogwheel at the top right allows you to select your audio device.

@LPChip unfortunately it is. I use Windows since 3.11 so this change is something I have investigated a lot before asking the question (I work in IT). My problem happens with a SHOKZ headset (just to set some concrete information)

I'm not using Windows 11, and I know they changed it in Windows 11, so I can't tell you how to change the audio device so that the windows volume mixer picks it up correctly.

First, LPChip is correct that the top slider is the master slider and, generally, for most applications, this will control all volumes. However...
A relatively recent development in various meeting software products is that their audio is separated from the overall system volume controls, and the result is that, sometimes, only their own application volume controls will control their volume.
The reason for this exemption is not to make meeting volume control more annoying and complicated, but to allow meeting audio to run in and out over a device separate from the system audio (the RESULT of this exemption is definitely that volume control in a meeting IS more annoying and complicated). Your master volume slider controls the volume of a specific selected audio device. You can change this device using he controls in the taskbar.
The Fix
The general rule to get meeting applications such as Teams or Zoom to "obey" the system master audio volume is to make sure that your systems' main audio output and the meeting software audio output devices are the same.
